# Hiding ¶ line break character in NetBeans editor

Tags: netbeans

How can I hide the `¶` line break character in the NetBeans 8.2 IDE Editor?

[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To hide the `space` or `tab` characters, follow these simple steps:

1. Open your NetBeans IDE 8.2
   [related image: [A file is opened with showing the hidden characters](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOQ5p.png) ]
2. Go / Click "View" menu
   [related image: [Clicking the view menu in NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/msCMA.png) ]
3. Remove the tick mark beside of "Show Non-Printable Characters".
   [related image: [After clicking the option, the hidden characters are hidden.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15M0I.png) ]

Again, to show these characters, use these steps:

1. Open your NetBeans IDE 8.2
[related image: [A file is opened with hiding the hidden characters.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/15M0I.png) ]

2. Click "View" menu from menu-bar
[related image: [Clicking the `view` menu in NetBeans](https://i.stack.imgur.com/lroJ4.png) ]

3. Click "Show Non-Printable Characters" to put a tick mark beside the menu-item.
[related image: [After clicking the option, the hidden characters are shown again.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/sOQ5p.png) ]

Thats it!

Thanks for asking questions in AskUbuntu.